# How to return null when return type is vector<int>

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to distinguish the return value when `targetSum=0` and when `targetSum<0`, I need an empty array when `targetSum=0` and `NULL` when `targetSum<0`. As `Null` gives error of return type so, I decided to return {-1} as array's first elment, but that give me following error

```
howsum.cpp:19:45: error: could not convert 'remainderResult.std::vector<int>::push_back((*(const value_type*)(& numbers.std::vector<int>::operator[](((std::vector<int>::size_type)i)))))' from 'void' to 'std::vector<int>'
   19 |             return remainderResult.push_back(numbers[i]);
      |                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                             |
      |                                             void
```

My code:

```
vector<int> howSum(int targetSum, vector<int> numbers, int size){
    if(targetSum == 0) return {};
    if(targetSum < 0) return {-1};

    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){  
        int remainder = targetSum - numbers[i];
        vector<int> remainderResult = howSum(remainder, numbers, size);
        if(remainderResult[0] != -1)
            return remainderResult.push_back(numbers[i]);   
    }
    return {-1};
}
```

Comment: You're trying to return **the result of** `remainderResult.push_back()`...

Comment: Null is a pointer value. Vectors can't be null. They can be empty.

Comment: Take a step back and explain **what** this function is supposed to do. What is the problem that it's supposed to solve? That mix of looping and recursion is hard to understand, and probably unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::optional<T>` to return any value *optionally*.

For instance:

```cpp
#include <optional>

std::optional<int> maybe_int(const bool flag) {
    if (flag) {
        return 44;
    } else {
        return std::nullopt;
    }
}

// Somewhere else...

auto some_int { maybe_int(flag) };
if (some_int) {
    // Do something with *some_int
}
```

`std::optional<T>` behaves like a pointer, and it can have an "invalid" state represented by `std::nullopt`, while having by-value semantics (i.e. no memory allocations). Remember to use `std::move` to avoid unnecessary copies when boxing or unboxing an optional.

If your compiler doesn't support C++17, I recommend you to update your compiler. If that's not possible, you can use Boost or use `std::unique_ptr<T>` to achieve a similar result.

Answer (score 0):

Your title doesn't match your question body.

A `std::vector<int>` is always a vector, it is never `NULL` (or equal to `nullptr`).

The reason you can't `return remainderResult.push_back(numbers[i]);` is because the result of `push_back` is nothing, not the vector.

You will need to `push_back` then return.

However you will then find you have undefined behaviour if you reach your result, as you look at the first element of an empty vector when target is 0.

```
std::vector<int> howSum(int targetSum, std::vector<int> numbers, int size){
    if(targetSum < 0) return {-1};

    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){  
        int remainder = targetSum - numbers[i];
        if (remainder == 0) {
             return { numbers[i] };
        }
        std::vector<int> remainderResult = howSum(remainder, numbers, size);
        if(remainderResult[0] != -1) {
            remainderResult.push_back(numbers[i]);
            return remainderResult;
        }
    }
    return {-1};
}
```